# How to get iOS App crash logs from Windows machine

Tags: ios, windows, logs

I am working as a manual tester from past 2 years(mostly worked on web applications) in one of the software testing company and now I have just started functional testing on mobile devices. My App on iOS device is crashing out frequently and my developer suggested me to share the crash logs for the same so that he can debug the issue but I have no idea about it.

I use Windows 7 machine here. Can anyone please help me on how to get the crash logs for iOS app from my Windows Machine?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about iOS debugging and not testing specific, better asked on: http://apple.stackexchange.com/ or maybe stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am working as a functional engineer in qa outsourcing company, where we provide qa services to the offshore companies. We work on both automation & manual testing and clients (Development Team) always ask us for the Crash logs, so that they can easily debug the issue.

Following are the steps, that we follow to get the crash logs:

1. Install iTools (Freeware) on Windows device.
2. Connect iphone to the machine using USB.
3. The device will be auto detected by the windows machine.
4. Open iTools and wait till your iphone is visible.
5. Go to the menu: Advance option> Crash Reports> then sort your crash report date wise.

Please feel free to ask, if you need crash logs on the Mac machine as well.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://help.getpocket.com/article/1098-how-to-find-the-iphone-ipad-app-crash-logs) provides the steps below for windows users

Windows Vista/7 Users

1. Open any Windows Explorer Window (My Computer, My Documents, etc.)
2. Enter %appdata%, and press enter
3. Navigate to Roaming > Apple computer > Logs > CrashReporter > Mobile Device > *Device Name*. (Note: your device name appears in iTunes on the left side, under 'Devices')
4. You will see at least one item starting with 'ReadItLaterPro'. Copy any that you find to your Desktop.
5. Attach the file(s) to your reply, or send them to support [at] getpocket [dot] com.

Comment: No problem! Give them a go and mark whichever suits your needs best as the accepted answer.

Comment: The solution provided by Vishal worked for me but thanks alot for your help!